# Windows 7 not booting

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, bcdedit

My computer was updating and was then mistakenly turned off. It is showing me the following error

File: clfs.sys
  Status:0xc000000f

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: clfs.sys 

  Status: 0xc000000f
```

Disk repair doesn't work, but I have noticed a few things. When I go into command prompt (through the disk repair setting). When I change it to C:
I see the bcdedit files i created and nothing else, but when I change it to D: I see all my files: program, downloads, etc. My boot partition should be C: not D:
First i would like to change the directory then try and fix the problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your boot is pointing to D is that Windows was probably using a temporary partition to boot from while updating, so that it could modify files and not be using them.

Unfortunately, the only practical solution is to re-install Windows using bootable media. However, since Windows 7 is not really downloadable anymore, you may need to upgrade to Windows 10.

If you still have the Windows 7 disc, then you can simply boot from that and choose to 'upgrade', keeping your files.